# How to functionally Join multiple Deedle series in C#?

Tags: c#, f#, functional-programming, tail-recursion, deedle

i am thinking to use deedle to join hundreds of series into a frame. what is the best functional way to achieve this?

The immediate (imperative) thought is to create a frame object holder outside of the loop. then within the loop this object older is used as the left hand side of the series join.

on a second thought, `C#` tail recursion? i have done some research i am a bit lost as whether c# can do tail recursion. There is only F`#` example from Tomas' book 'functional programming for real world'

Also has anyone had deedle frame with hundreds of columns (1000 rows)? is there a big performance impact? this may sound excessive but it is done in spreadsheet quite commonly

Any suggestion is welcome.
Thank you
casbby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right approach for creating a frame depends on where your data is coming from.

If you already have all the series and you want to create a frame that contains them as columns, then the method `Frame.FromColumns` is probably the way to go. The method takes a collection of key value pairs where the key is the column name and the value is the column (series).

Here is a minimal example that creates an array of key value pairs with names and series:

```
var cols = new KeyValuePair<string, Series<int, object>>[]{
  KeyValue.Create("IDs", (new object[] {1,2,2}).ToOrdinalSeries() ),
  KeyValue.Create("Namess", (new object[] {"A", "B", "C"}).ToOrdinalSeries() )
};
var frame = Frame.FromColumns(cols);
```

I assume that in your case, you already have the series in some collection, so the functional approach is to use LINQ and `Select` to project your data into the right format. So your code might look something like:

```
var cols = someSource.Select(item =>
  KeyValue.Create(item.Key, item.Series));
var frame = Frame.FromColumns(cols);
```

The `FromColumns` operation is using outer join under the cover, but it is optimized (e.g. if you have series with the same index). There is a bunch of additional examples in the [C# documentation for Deedle](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/csharpframe.html).

Comment: Once again, thank you very Tomas. After I posted question i started to muck around in VS and eventually came up with something a little similar to your suggestion:
Series<int, double> s1 = new SeriesBuilder<int, double>() { { 1, 2.5 }, { 2, 3.1 }, { 3, 4.5 } }.Series;
Series<int, double> s2 = new SeriesBuilder<int, double>() { { 1, double.NaN }, { 2, 3.1 }, { 3, double.NaN } }.Series;
var s = new SeriesBuilder<string, Series<int, double>();
s.Add("A", s1).Add("B", s1).Add("C", s1).Add("D", s2);            var sObjt = s.Series; 
var dFrame = Frame.FromColumns<string, int, double>(sObjt);